# How to compile flex code in order to obtain a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, c, flex-lexer

I'd like to compile my [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) `scanner.l` in order to get a dynamic library to be called from my C/C++ project. What is the correct way of doing it? Will I be able to simultaneously call the scanner from my C/C++ program in different threads?

Comment: The same way you make any other dynamic library with your compiler.  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I use gcc. Using flex scanner.l I generate lex.yy.c, then how can I call the scanner from another program?

Comment: Have your other program call the method(s) defined in lex.yy.c.  When you go to compile, tell gcc to compile both your primary program and lex.yy.c.  Making it a dynamic library seems a bit overkill.

Comment: I want to have a .so because I want to learn how to do it. In past I already tried the method you describe and there were many limitations. I remember one: lex.yy.c methods use many global variables which made impossible to run the scanner on different threads. Having a dynamic library may be a step to solve the multithread problem.

Comment: Flex can generate a re-entrant parser (safe for multi threaded applications): http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Reentrant.html

Comment: And if you just want to learn how to create a shared library with gcc, a quick google search should turn up plenty of good results.  If you run into specific issues you can be helped further from there.

Answer (score 2):

(Question answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Josh wrote:

> The same way you make any other dynamic library with your compiler.
>
> Have your other program call the method(s) defined in lex.yy.c. When you go to compile, tell gcc to compile both your primary program and lex.yy.c. Making it a dynamic library seems a bit overkill.
>
> Flex can generate a re-entrant parser (safe for multi threaded applications):
>   [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant.html)
>
> And if you just want to learn how to create a shared library with gcc, a quick google search should turn up plenty of good results. If you run into specific issues you can be helped further from there.